# How to align button with icons in ionic

Tags: html, css, ionic-framework

[image: Buttons]

I would like to align these buttons with text to a proper format. I'm using ionic and I want something like how bootstrap gives with `fa-fw`
Here is the code :

```
<div class="content padding">
      <button class="button button-block button-positive icon ion-log-in" ng-click="login(username, password)">&nbsp;Login</button>
      <a class="button button-block button-transparent icon ion-ios-help-empty">&nbsp;Forgot Password</a>
      <button class="button button-block button-stable icon ion-key" ng-click="register(username, password)">&nbsp;Register</button>
</div>
```

Comment: can you post html with your css?

Comment: I am using ionic. There is no custom css so far.

Answer (score 0):

In Ionic icon-left and icon-right class are available with button and also you use your customized css with button for more help go to [here](http://ionicframework.com/docs/components/#icon-buttons).

For example ,

```
<button class="button icon-left ion-home">Home</button>
<a class="button icon-right ion-chevron-right button-calm">Learn More</a>
```

Hope this will help you !

Answer (score 0):

You can use in-built class in ionic like `icon-left icon-right`. If your need more flexibility with the icons like fa-aw, either you need to write your own custom css or use font-awesome itself in your project

```html
<link href="//code.ionicframework.com/nightly/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="//code.ionicframework.com/nightly/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<a class="button icon-right ion-chevron-right button-calm">Learn More</a>
<br>

<a class="button icon-left ion-chevron-left button-clear button-dark">Back</a>
<br>


<i class="fa fa-camera-retro fa-lg"></i> fa-lg
<i class="fa fa-camera-retro fa-2x"></i> fa-2x
<i class="fa fa-camera-retro fa-3x"></i> fa-3x
<i class="fa fa-camera-retro fa-4x"></i> fa-4x
<i class="fa fa-camera-retro fa-5x"></i> fa-5x

<a class="button button-icon icon ion-settings"></a>
<br>

<a class="button button-outline icon-right ion-navicon button-balanced">Reorder</a>
```